# 2018: a year in moderation

Tags: discussion, moderation, statistics

It's New Year's Day in [Stack Exchange land](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zulu_Time)...

A distinguishing characteristic of these sites is how they are moderated:

> We designed the Stack Exchange network engine to be mostly self-regulating, in that we amortize the overall moderation cost of the system across thousands of teeny-tiny slices of effort contributed by regular, everyday users.
> -- [A Theory of Moderation](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/05/a-theory-of-moderation/)

While there certainly are [Moderators](https://stackoverflow.blog/2018/11/21/our-theory-of-moderation-re-visited/) here, a significant amount of the *moderation* is done by ordinary people, using the privileges
they've earned by virtue of their contributions to the site. Each of you contributes a little bit of time and effort, and together you accomplish much.

As we enter a new year, let's pause and reflect, taking a moment to appreciate the work that we do here together.
To that end, here is how the moderation done here on Travel breaks down by activity over the past 12 months:

```
                 Action                  Moderators Community¹
---------------------------------------- ---------- ----------
Users suspended²                                  4         13
Users destroyed                                  81          0
Users deleted                                     4          0
Users contacted                                  12          0
Tasks reviewed³: Suggested Edit queue           165      3,044
Tasks reviewed³: Reopen Vote queue               73      1,628
Tasks reviewed³: Low Quality Posts queue        129      5,927
Tasks reviewed³: Late Answer queue               99      1,698
Tasks reviewed³: First Post queue                28      8,165
Tasks reviewed³: Close Votes queue              789     10,525
Tags merged                                      13          0
Tag synonyms proposed                             8          2
Tag synonyms created                              8          0
Revisions redacted                               15          0
Questions unprotected                             4          2
Questions reopened                               93         47
Questions protected                              39        340
Questions migrated                              145          0
Questions merged                                  2          0
Questions flagged⁴                               43      3,058
Questions closed                              1,218      2,638
Question flags handled⁴                         697      2,404
Posts unlocked                                    4         23
Posts undeleted                                  69         84
Posts locked                                     19        620
Posts deleted⁵                                1,681      3,232
Posts bumped                                      0        151
Comments undeleted                               44          0
Comments flagged                                 10      2,406
Comments deleted⁶                             4,446      4,178
Comment flags handled                         1,640        776
Bounties canceled                                44          0
Answers flagged                                 143      9,048
Answer flags handled                          5,419      3,772
All comments on a post moved to chat            150          0
```

#### Footnotes

¹ "Community" here refers both to [the membership of Travel](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users) *without* [diamonds next to their names](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators), and to the automated systems otherwise known as [user #-1](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/-1).

² The system will suspend users under three circumstances: when a user is recreated after being previously suspended, when a user is recreated after being destroyed for spam or abuse, and when a network-wide suspension is in effect on an account.

³ This counts every review that was submitted (not skipped) - so the 2 suggested edits reviews needed to approve an edit would count as 2, the goal being to indicate the frequency of moderation actions. This also applies to flags, etc.

⁴ Includes close flags (but *not* close or reopen votes).

⁵ This ignores numerous deletions that happen automatically in response to some other action.

⁶ This includes comments deleted by their own authors (which also account for some number of handled comment flags).

Wishing you all a happy new year...

Comment: It would be quite interesting to read a personal look back by our elected Travel SE moderators on their year 2018, regarding moderation, site goals, etc.

Answer (score 5):

Thank you to all the work that moderators and users do. Even though I haven’t been on this site for long, I know it is a hard work to moderate the site.

Remember everyone can help not just moderators. Thanks all to this who created this tool to allow us to appreciate all the work that is done.

Answer (score 2):

As your newest mod I have no long experience being a mod on this site but I know that we have a good active community and many members do their part in community moderation.
That works so well that the mods mostly can restrict themselves doing the flags, (many of which will also be listed in the review queues, so mods to handle some of those as well.)

It seems most days the queues and flags are all handled, and no bad situations linger for days on end, so I way we are successful as members together with the mod team.

I hope the members on this site are happy with the way moderation works.
I welcome constructive comments and try to adjust my way of working to what people tell me.